# "java.lang.illegalargumentexception: already added lokhttp3/address" when installing Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.*

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play-services, mapbox-android

I'm building a `Xamarin.Android` application, but I'm having troubles every time I add any `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.*` NuGet packages. First time my `.csproj` was corrupted, and I had to start the project all over and include all files in a new project. I avoided those libs, but now I need them. This time, I get this error

> java.lang.illegalargumentexception: already added lokhttp3/address

I've searched for days, but have not been able to find an answer. Anyone who knows how to resolve the `java.lang.illegalargumentexception: already added` error in `Xamarin.Android`?

EDIT:

I've found that I can reproduce this error by create a blank Xamarin.Android project and import package XBindings.MapboxLocationLayer.Droid as the only package.

Comment: well it seems you are trying to install something that already exist

Comment: It's not when I am installing, but when I am building that this error comes. I've read that the problem is there is two .jar files of same type, and then the checksum fails.

Comment: do you have solution versioning in your system ?

Comment: Do you mean like GitHub/repository? Or do you mean if the solution has a version and the projects has a version?- Like Version Number 1 and Version Name 1.0 ?

Comment: Please include a full list of your package references. This will help determine where the duplicate is coming from.

Comment: I'm talking about repository

Comment: I created an empty Xamarin.Android project and importet the XBindings.MapboxLocationLayer.Droid to reproduce this error. This is the package.config
https://pastebin.com/s20WzHXX

Comment: Hi, if you have seen my message, you need leave me a message, let me know you have tested my answer, and whether it works for you.

Comment: Hey Joe, I'm incredibly busy at work right now, I have seen your answer and can't wait to try it out. I'll answer as soon as I get to try it, it will be later today or tomorrow

Comment: @RasmusPedersen How did you fix this issue? I have this exact problem. I have both the Naxam.SquareUp.OkHttp3 and Square.OkHttp3 packages in my project and i'm getting this same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the main author of these libraries and the founder of [NAXAM](https://naxam.net), the company behind a lot of binding libraries: MAPBOX, BRAINTREE, STRIPE.

I have supported to resolve the issue.

Regarding this issue, plz uninstall NAXAM/Xbindings packages then re-install only direct reference packages.
It's the issue of history, very sorry for this inconvenient.

- Some may be interested in Mapbox Navigation library as well, plz read our readme carefully because there are Android Support packages un-published by XAMARIN yet

> In the mean time, packages for Android.Arch.Core.Runtime and Android.Arch.Lifetime.Extensions aren't published by Xamarin yet. Plz add a nuget source to https://www.myget.org/F/xbindings/api/v3/index.json either directly in Visual Studio Nuget Packages Source or via nuget.config file.

- Some packages' versions are ending with `beta` and VS doesn't understand them as dependencies, plz add them manually. They are beta because at the time of their creation, native libraries are beta.

Cheers.

Tuyen, Founder of NAXAM - https://naxam.net

Comment: I don't understand why it works on my computer well, not work for @Rasmus Pedersen in the same way.

Comment: I have tried two ways to solve it, but both of them can't  work for @Rasmus.

Comment: @JoeLvMSFT It happens always :). Great that it works at your side.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Naxam.SquareUp.OkHttp3`, and Enable Multi-Dex will build successfully.

Both `Naxam.SquareUp.OkHttp3` and `Square.OkHttp3` contain the okhttp, so you need remove one. And then you will get the error: `java.exe exited with code 2`, [refer to this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/97803/getting-error-java-exe-exited-with-code-2), you need Enable Multi-Dex.

Comment: When i try to uninstall Naxam.SquareUp.OkHttp3, it says
Unable to uninstall 'Naxam.SquareUp.OkHttp3.3.6.0' because 'Naxam.SquareUp.OkHttp3.LoggingInterceptor.3.6.0' depends on it.

When i try to uninstall Square.OkHttp3, it says
Unable to uninstall 'Square.OkHttp3.3.8.1' because 'Naxam.Mapbox.Droid.5.2.0, Naxam.Mapbox.Services.Android.Telemetry.2.2.9.3, Square.Retrofit2.2.2.0' depend on it.

Comment: Update all of the packages and enable Multi-Dex.

Comment: When I enabled Mutil Dex I was able to uninstall `Naxam.SquareUp.OkHttp3`, but now I get a new error
`java.lang.illegalargumentexception: already added lokhttp3/address` together with 20 warnings saying `can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF].......`

Comment: Don't uninstall any thing. Just update all of the packages and enable Multi-Dex.

Comment: Now I get this error `java.lang.illegalArgumentException: already added lokhttp3/Callback`. I did this: Start fresh solution, add blank Xamarin.Android project, add package `XBindings.MapboxLocationLayer.Droid` , update all NuGet packages, enable mutli-dex. But the issue still remains